# How to have AppBarLayout floating above content like in recent Google design

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, material-design

I am trying to recreate [this design](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj16rzK3svhAhVPY6wKHQWXCJ8QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.idownloadblog.com%2F2019%2F01%2F29%2Fgmail-material-design%2F&psig=AOvVaw22ktxtWN4Xa4h8aAJxo8qc&ust=1555199158184278) The screenshot does not show it, but if the user scrolls down some and scrolls back up slightly the toolbar is hovering above the email content.

My app on the other hand looks like this

[image: Toolbar has its own space so you can not see the list content below it]

As you can see, the appbarlayout space has a list below it which hide the card content below it. The appbar layout has a transparent background so not sure why this is happening.

Here is the relevant layout file:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/timeline"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/custom_row_tweet" />

            </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/top_offset"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:onClick="searchTweets"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                    ...

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:onClick="addClick"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_tweet"
                android:tag="0"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:layout_anchor="@+id/timeline"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="end|bottom" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I saw one answer a while ago which suggested giving a negative margin and adding a placeholder item as the first item in the list but unfortunately this would be difficult to do since I am using PagedListAdapter getting items directly from my database.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced kinda the same issue when trying something similar. What I was able to achieve was this: [Recycler view top padding = status bar height + toolbar height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri24J.png). Unfortunately, I didn't use any sort of behavior here and the toolbar position is fixed.
Here's how I achieved this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?primaryColor"
tools:context=".ui.fragments.mainactivity.library.LibraryFragment">

<com.simplecityapps.recyclerview_fastscroll.views.FastScrollRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.paolovalerdi.abbey.views.StatusBarView
        android:id="@+id/statusBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_padding" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/Toolbar"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/userImage"
                    style="@style/ToolbarIcon"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_item_margin"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/default_artist_image"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarTile"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/library"
                    android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
                    tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap,RtlSymmetry" />

                <com.paolovalerdi.abbey.views.IconImageView
                    android:id="@+id/searchIcon"
                    style="@style/ToolbarIcon"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_item_margin"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/cab_stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

StatusBarView.Kt

```
class StatusBarView : View {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet,
        defStyleAttr: Int
) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
)

override fun onApplyWindowInsets(insets: WindowInsets): WindowInsets {
    val lp = layoutParams
    lp.height = insets.systemWindowInsetTop
    layoutParams = lp
    return super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets)
}
```

And all you have to do is apply the padding-top to your recycler view:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(view)
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { v, insets ->
        topPadding = insets.systemWindowInsetTop + resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mini_player_height)
        recyclerView.updatePadding(top = topPadding)
        insets
    }
}
```

Noted that I request insets because this is done within a fragment and then all you have to do es just set a listener to the root view (or your recyclerview). Also your recycler view should have clip android:clipToPadding="false".
Hope this helps :)

I'll leave some post that helped me to understand how to handle insets like a pro.

[Windows Insets + Fragment Transitions](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/windows-insets-fragment-transitions-9024b239a436)
, [WindowInsets — Listeners to layouts](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/windowinsets-listeners-to-layouts-8f9ccc8fa4d1)

Comment: Unfortunately the whole point of this is that I keep it such that the toolbar will hide on scroll, otherwise I could just do this with a constraint layout alone.